# unable to update record on overridden edit page. record is getting inserted instead of update

Tags: apex

I overrided lead edit page and new page which does not accept duplicate records.I used the same save and save & new button for both the pages.so when i click on save button after editing the record  it is getting inserted again.i tried to update in many ways but unable to solve it.

```
public class LeadNewPage {
    public Lead leads{set;get;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller{set;get;}

    public LeadNewPage (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public pagereference save () {
        leads=(Lead)controller.getRecord();
        Integer count = [select count() from Lead where firstname=:leads.firstname];

        if (count > 0) {
               ApexPages.Message msg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'duplicate exists');
               ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
               return null;
        } else {
            insert leads;
            pagereference p = new pagereference('/'+leads.Id);
            return p;
        }

    }

    public PageReference saveNew () {
        leads=(Lead)controller.getRecord();
        integer count=[select count() from Lead where firstname=:leads.firstname];

        if (count > 0) {
               ApexPages.Message msg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'duplicate exists');
               ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
               return null;
        } else {
               insert leads;
               pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/NewLeadPage');
               p.setRedirect(true);
               return p;
        }
    }

    public pagereference edit() {
        pagereference p = new pagereference('/apex/EditLeadPage');
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Duplicate Management instead. There's no need to do this in code these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `insert` statement to [`upsert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm).

Problem is because in edit page, the lead has its Id. An upsert operation handles both insert as well as update.

```
// this would become
// insert leads;
upsert leads;
```

Note: recommended way of redirection is [`Page.existingPageName`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)

Here is the optimized version of your code, combined save method in one. Always try to reuse the code:

```
public class LeadNewPage {
    public Lead leads{set;get;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller{set;get;}
    public LeadNewPage (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public pagereference save() {
        return save(new pagereference('/' + leads.Id));
    }

    public PageReference saveNew() {
        pagereference p = Page.NewLeadPage;
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return save(p);
    } 

    private Pagereference save(Pagereference pr) {
        leads=(Lead)controller.getRecord();
        Integer count = [select count() from Lead where firstname=:leads.firstname];

        if (count > 0) {
            ApexPages.Message msg=new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'duplicate exists');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        } else {
            upsert leads;
            return pr;
        }
    }

    public pagereference edit() {
        pagereference p = Page.EditLeadPage;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: here u need to understand one thing that if count >0 (throws the error message).so what happens is again in the edit page the same dml operation will be performed and it gives count as 1 then again msg will be thrown..where is the chance to update then.

Comment: Is that a request or an order? Let me think!